# Writing a protocol that has client and server side software

Tags: server, protocols, saas

I will be developing a protocol that will encompass a client and a server module. 
Several protocols that are close to the one I have in mind exist, but I want to make something simpler with less overhead and with something I have more control on.

The protocol I will be doing can and will be run almost in any scenario, local, web, lan, internet, etc. It can also run on a single box.

My question is, how can I start developing for the server side of the protocol?
Any ideas, insights, key words, starting points would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: This is quite an open-ended question; it needs fleshing out in more detail. Firstly, is this protocol intended to run over the web? The internet? On a local network? Or on a single box? This is quite a fundamental question and the answers will strongly dictate how you design the protocol. The other thing to ask is have you looked at any existing protocols rather than rolling your own? The kind of thing you're asking for sounds like a problem that has likely been solved already; what advantage will you get from writing your own vs using one that exists already?

Comment: Thanks @Simba for your feedback. Accordingly I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to develop the protocol yourself and then use it? or you are looking for a good protocol to use?

If second, I have recently worked with "Websocket" protocol which enables clients to communicate with each other via a server. It is a really good protocol and there are libraries in .NET ( >= 4.5), JAVA, Javascript, ... It is also supported in many browsers.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to develop my own protocol. Basically, it's quite straight forward. But I believe the application could be a bit hard if not planned correctly, hence my question here.